# Is there a way to get a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetKey?

Tags: c#

I'd expect this to be a duplicate but i haven't found one, so sorry if it is. I need to get the actual key in a dictionary, so not the one that i have but the one that is stored in the dictionary. So smilar to `HashSet<TKey>.TryGetValue`:

```
HashSet<string> _validCountryCodes = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "CH", "DE", "US" // and so on...    
};

string? GetValidIsoCountry(string? countryCode)
{
    return countryCode != null 
        && _validCountryCodes.TryGetValue(countryCode, out string? actualCode)
            ? actualCode
            : null;
}
```

But how to do this with a dictionary efficiently? Of course i don't want to loop all key-value pairs:

```
Dictionary<string, string > _countryNames = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    {"CH", "Switzerland"}, {"DE", "Germany"}, {"US", "USA"} // and so on...    
};

string GetValidIsoCountry(string countryCode)
{
    if (!_countryNames.ContainsKey(countryCode))
    {
        return null;
    }
        
    // what here, how do i resolve CH if i get ch? TryGetValue does not help because that's not what i need
}
```

Comment: What about building a second dictionary or storing a value tuple?

Comment: Methinks you'll need to resort to reflection....

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Country>`

Comment: @HansPassant: thats just an example, you can have anything as key with custom IEqualityComparers passed to the constructor. So i want the key that is stored in the dictionary, no matter what is stored in the Value. Actually i'm missing a TryGetKeyValue which returns both. I would add it as extension if there was an efficient way. Maybe you guys have an idea.

Comment: You may be able to examine the implementation of `Hashset.TryGetValue` and implement something similar in a class derived from `Dictionary`. It's not a given that that would be possible though.

Comment: The approach is universal, create a POCO or use a tuple to store the properties you want to access after retrieving it from the dictionary.  That's how HashSet works as well, it forces you to create such a POCO.  Post feature requests to the github site, beware it starts at -100 points.

Comment: For the record, I can see why no such method has been implemented. For a `Hashset`, it's more about using an existing instance of a complex reference type. You'd rarely use such a thing as the key in a `Dictionary` and, even if you did, the `Dictionary` is more about using the value than the key. It actually seems to me like you're misusing the `Dictionary` in the first place and the answer by Guru Stron corrects that misuse. We all use types in ways they weren't intended at various times but this seems to be one such time that it's catching up with you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: it's not unusual to store custom types in a dictionary key. And it's not unusual to use the dictionary constructor that takes `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`. So it can always be that the object that you have is different to the one stored in the dictionary but they are considered Equal to the current logic(comparer). But you need the original instance stored in the dictionary. But i see that there is no other way :)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing build-in as far as I know. I would argue that you actually store two pieces of information - actual IsoCode and Country name, so I would suggest to reflect it in the stored type. For example:

```
// or introduce "real" type here 
Dictionary<string, (string Code, string Name)> _countryNames2 = new (string Code, string Value)[]
    {
        ("CH", "Switzerland"), ("DE", "Germany"), ("US", "USA") // and so on...    
    }
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Code, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

string GetValidIsoCountry(string countryCode)
{
    if (!_countryNames2.TryGetValue(countryCode, out var tuple))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return tuple.Code;
}
```

Other than that I see following options:

- Switch to `Hashset<CountryPair>` with custom `IEqualityComparer<CountryPair>` which will use only code to manage the  equality and [`HashSet<T>.TryGetValue(T, T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.trygetvalue?view=net-7.0) to get the pair.
- Implementing your own version of dictionary which will return the `Entry` instead of the value (see [`internal ref TValue FindValue(TKey key)`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,397) or [`CollectionsMarshalHelper.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,662) for inspiration)
- Use reflection to with some copy-paste from sources (see links in the previous point)
- Create wrapper around dictionary which will maintain a separate index for keys.

Comment: Maybe it's possible in some cases, but not if you can't change the dictionary or don't want that because it's causing too much refactoring. I'd also say that the value does not need to be related to the key, so should not be a helper to resolve the real key. If it's sufficient to store both in the value, i'd say someone could directly use a `HashSet<T>` instead of a dictionary and a proper `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter while internally dictionary actually maintains collection of entries there is nothing out of the box provided to access it as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a custom comparer? You can save the last matching key in it.

```
class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public string lastMatchKey;

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        var r = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(x, y);
        if (r)
            lastMatchKey = x;
        return r;
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull]string obj)
        => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj);
}

static string GetValidIsoCountry(string countryCode)
{
    if (!_countryNames.ContainsKey(countryCode))
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (_countryNames.Comparer is CustomComparer cc)
        return cc.lastMatchKey;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Personally I would not go this way, but in general I like the creativity!

Comment: It's kind of an abuse of a comparer as a tracker, but at least it's a creative, efficient and working way. Maybe better to implement and try-cast to an `ITrackTheLastMatchingKey` ;-)